# BigInt conversion (gmp Bigint to botan bigint)

Tags: c++, cryptography, gmp, bigint, botan

I am using gmp to perform complex operation. I want to use Botan to perform cryptography functions. Problem is Both of them have their own Bigint function. So its creating problem on supplying bigint value used in gmp function to Botan function.

Can anyone help in this?

Comment: cannot convert parameter from Bigint to Botan::BigInt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`mpz_export`](http://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Import-and-Export.html#Integer-Import-and-Export) to export the GMP integer and the [`BigInt(const byte[], size_t)`](http://files.randombit.net/botan/doxygen/html/classBotan_1_1BigInt.html#6afd4a1efd873b59da7b71a2e07d4205) constructor to import it.